# Excel Macro Only recognizing some dates

Tags: excel, vba, date

I just got assigned editing this macro and I have not ever used one before. It is importing data from a text file. Everything is pretty much done I just have to add 6 or so columns. And I just followed what they had adding more to .TextFileColumnDataTypes and .TextFileFixedColumnWdiths.

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1,     1, 1, _
    1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2)
.TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(1, 8, 9, 8, 35, 35, 35, 6, 2, 1, 8, 21, 6, 6, 8, 2, 1, 1, _
    6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4, 8, 8, 6, 1, 8, 6, 1, 21, 9, 8, 35, 35, 35, 8, 2, 3, 6, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 1)
```

The weird part is that the third to last date field is recognized, while the fourth to last is not.

## The input file has the dates formatted as yyyymmdd. For example 20140530 For 5/30/2014. All dates are formatted this way, and I'm only having trouble with 3 or so of the ones I added.

Let me give more information, the line of data coming into my additions is this:

20131103SF081000050122013022620130401HT2013040220131009AD

And I want it to look like this:

11/3/2013   SF  81  50  12  02/26/2013  4/1/2013    HT  04/02/2013  10/9/2013   AD

When Instead It looks like this:

11/3/2013   SF  81  50  12  20130226    4/1/2013    HT  20130402    10/9/2013   AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the datatype array had an incorrect number of fields. Thus they were off by one. I did not notice it because it did not affect their results since the data for that column was not there yet. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It may be only a posting error, but your two arrays have different **Ubounds**

Comment: Well then it was that way before I added my eight fields. I just counted and mine are in fact the last eight. I also looked at what I was given and it is off by 1 as well. When the load happens the data is in all the correct columns, it just isn't formatted as a date for some of them.

Comment: Column widths array often has one less member since the last field is assumed to run to the end of the line (so no width is specified for that)